# Packet capture using PCAP library

Tags: c, wireshark, pcap

I have a scenario where a laptop is connected to an external hardware via ethernet.

The laptop can peek and poke the hardware, i.e. send a request packet to the hardware which generates a response packet from the hardware which the laptop receives and interprets.

This is all happening at the LLC layer, i.e. quite low level. I assemble the bytes constituting the request packet manually and likewise, I read the response packet bytes manually.

My problem is that I don't always 'see' the response packet. Running wireshark in parallel I can always see the request/response packets on the wire, but sometimes my code 'gets' the response packet and sometimes it doesn't - it seems non-deterministic as to whether the receive is success or failure.

This is the relevant code snippet outlining what I am doing:

```
/* send packet */
if (pcap_sendpacket(pdw_io->pcap, buf, LEN_ETH_REQ_PKT)==-1) {
    pcap_perror(pdw_io->pcap, 0);
    print_err_log(ERR_LOG, "Error: pcap_sendpacket failed", __FILE__, __LINE__);
    ret = 0;
}
free(buf);

/* logic here is that the next pkt after a request pkt is sent is *always*
 * the corresponding response pkt */
ret = pcap_next_ex(pdw_io->pcap, &hdr, &response_buf);
```

The send always works, i.e. I always see the packet in wireshark. I always see the response packet generated by the external hardware, its timestamp is approx 10us after the request. But pcap_next_ex() only return success (and fills response_buf with bytes) about half the time.

I am totally perplexed as to why this is. Note that there are no other LLC packets on the wire during this test, only the request response pair (as observed via wireshark)

Comment: Is your capture device set to non-blocking? if so, it might be a race condition then.

Comment: Also according to [the documentation](https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap_next_ex.3pcap.html) some platforms have an internal buffer timeout that could also make the function fail.

Comment: this buffering looks like a very likely contender for the issue, thanks for the pointer - currently investigating it... pcap_set_immediate_mode() looks relevant

Comment: I used pcap_getnonblock() and it returns 0 which I presume indicates its blocking, though https://linux.die.net/man/3/pcap_getnonblock doesn't explicitly say what the return values mean

Comment: @Neijwiert - yep it was buffer timeout, happy to accept your comments as answer if you want to cut and paste as such..

Comment: I'm happy to have helped, but I don't really know right now what a workaround could be and an answer wouldn't really be complete without one :)